# How to pass data from Main page to tabLayout (TabItem )

Tags: android

I am a new application developer trying to transfer data from activity to tabLayout (TabItem ). 
Firstly I make a data pass or intent from (recyclerview) to activity that contains  tabLayout (TabItem ) by this code :

```
   public static final String EXTRA_FROM = "FROMPL";

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(int position) {
       Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, 
       com.example.myapplication.Fragmant.StatusFragment.class);
       ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);
       detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_FROM, clickedItem.getCreator());
       startActivity(detailIntent);
   }
```

And I Receive data on the next Activity that contains tabLayout (TabItem ) with the following code:

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
     final String FROMPL = i.getStringExtra("FROMPL");
     text.setText(FROMPL);
```

To here everything is fine , And the data can be used on Main page .but the problem that I have now
In this activity after I Receive data how I can send it to one of tabLayout or one TabItem ?Picture for clarification

[image]

I need to transfer data to it  to display different data separately in each one.

All my code :

```
public class MainActivityFargmain extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PageAdapter pageAdapter;
    TabItem tabChats;
    TabItem tabStatus;
    TabItem tabCalls;
    EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_m);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabChats = findViewById(R.id.tabChats);
        tabStatus = findViewById(R.id.tabStatus);
        tabCalls = findViewById(R.id.tabCalls);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);

     Intent i = getIntent();
     final String FROMPL = i.getStringExtra("FROMPL");
     text.setText(FROMPL);


        pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            R.color.colorAccent));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            R.color.colorAccent));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                                R.color.colorAccent));
                    }
                } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                                android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    }
                } else {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            R.color.colorPrimary));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            R.color.colorPrimary));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                                R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    }
}
```

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_chats, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_chat) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numOfTabs;

    PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ChatFragment();
            case 1:
                return new StatusFragment();
            case 2:
                return new CallFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Do you want to set the text of the tab item from the data received from the intent?

Comment: No brother, I want to put data received in text and that text uesing in tab item..

Comment: You can call the setText() on Tab ...For ex : tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Some Text That Is Passed"); I recommend you to go through documentation once

Comment: It is like process of pass data from activity to another activity , but now from activity to tab item. Why I do that? because I try to pass data from recyclerview to tab item And I cant do it So now I pass data from recyclerview to main activity that activity have tab item and now I want to pass that data again from main activity to tab item

Comment: I updated my question (picture)  to make it more clear . my brother I try to pass data from recyclerview to tab item to display it . like that . But I couldn't directly do that. So now I pass data from recyclerview firstly to activity  of tab item and now I want pass that data to tab item

Comment: You must pass the value to Fragments in a bundle then in individual fragments you can access those dag...

Comment: How I can do that sorry but I'm a new developer don't know everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity create 2 functions:

- setData()
- getData()

In your MainActivity() add the following:

```
public String data;

public void setData(String passedData){
this.data = passedData
}
```

OnClick Listener function:

```
@Override 
public void onItemClick(int position) {
setData("my String");
}
```

declare getData() that returns data.

```
public void getData(){
return data;
}
```

in your fragment

```
MainActivityFargmain activity = (MainActivityFargmain) getActivity();
String dataReceived = activity.getData();
```

Comment: it works great. Thank you very much. I wish to you all the best.But can you tell me what is the difference between This process and Use Bundle؟

Comment: they both do the same thing passing data. In bundle, you just launch a new fragment and pass bundle to it, all other fragment doesn't know what data transferred except the fragment will be transferred. 
In this type, it's more public, as all child fragments can get data

Comment: Brother if I want to send more than one String how I do?like setData("my String1,myString2,myString3");like that?And How I will can Received it?